# ¿Cómo puedo trabajar con distintas palabras de una cadena, sin saber cuál será la frase?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

no se me ocurre de que manera hacer esto... Necesito ingresar una oración (por ejemplo: "espero las vacaciones con ansias") y debo quitarles las vocales a las palabras que tengan 6 o más letras, pero a las demás no:

```
frase = input().lower() #ingresar la frase 

palabra = frase.split(" ")[-1]
if (len(palabra) >= 6):
   vocales = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') #definir lo que se quitará
   for letra in vocales:
       frase = frase.replace(letra, "") #se eliminan las vocales
   frase = frase[::1]
   print (frase)
else:
     print(frase)
```

Esto imprime:

```
spr ls vccns cn nss
```

Debería imprimir:

```
spr las vccns con nss
```

Se me olvido poner que idealmente no se usen funciones, de todas maneras gracias a todos los que están ayudando.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que crees que es palabra?????

Comment: Si no quieres usar funciones basta que copies el código de la función dentro del bucle, en cualquiera de las soluciones que las usen.

Answer (score 4):

simplemente debes hacer un `for` para iterar en cada palabra

```py
frase ="espero las vacaciones con ansias"
vocales = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') #definir lo que se quitará
nueva_palabra = []

for palabra in frase.split(" "):
  if len(palabra)>=6:
    for voc in vocales:
      palabra = palabra.replace(voc, "")
  nueva_palabra.append(palabra)

nueva_palabra = " ".join(nueva_palabra)
```

Answer (score 4):

Tienes un problema de lógica que podría resolverse:

```
palabra = frase.split(" ")[-1]
if (len(palabra) >= 6):
```

Con esto solo estas verificando la primer palabra de la lista, pero tienes que verificar cada una de ellas, por lo que esto debería estar dentro de un ciclo que itere sobre cada palabra y luego si la iteración sobre las vocales.

De todas forma te sugiero una forma bastante sencilla, aunque distinta al enfoque que estás usando:

```
import re

def del_vowels(text):
    return re.compile('([aáeéiíoóuú])').sub('', text)

frase = " ".join([del_vowels(word) if len(word) >= 6 else word for word in frase.split()])
```

Detalle:

- Con expresiones regulares eliminamos las vocales de un texto (`del_vowels()`)
- Con una comprensión de listas

  - Dividimos la frase en una lista de palabras mediante `frase.split()`
  - Aplicamos la función `del_vowels()` en cada palabra de al menos 6 caracteres.
- Por último, volvemos a unir todo separando cada frase con un espacio

Answer (score 4):

### Por qué no funciona tu código

Tienes esto:

```
palabra = frase.split(" ")[-1]
```

que se queda solo con la última palabra de la frase. Y después esto:

```
if (len(palabra) >= 6):
```

que verifica por tanto si la última palabra tiene 6 letras o más. Y cuando eso se cumple, haces esto:

```
   vocales = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') #definir lo que se quitará
   for letra in vocales:
       frase = frase.replace(letra, "") #se eliminan las vocales
```

que elimina las vocales de la frase completa. Así que quitas las vocales a toda la frase, si la última palabra tiene más de 6 letras. Obviamente no era eso lo que querías hacer.

Después también haces `frase = frase[::1]` lo que no tiene mucho sentido, pero tampoco hace daño pues simplemente saca una copia de `frase`.

### Qué habría que hacer

Empezabas bien con el `split()` pero en vez de quedarte con la última palabra debes iterar por la lista resultante. Cada elemento de la lista es una palabra, y debes mirar su longitud. Si tiene 6 o más letras, le quitas las vocales.

### Código

Para mejorar la legibilidad, voy a poner en una función la parte que quita las vocales, tal y como tú la tenías:

```
def quitar_vocales(palabra):
   vocales = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') #definir lo que se quitará
   for letra in vocales:
       palabra = palabra.replace(letra, "")
   return palabra
```

Con ayuda de esta función el programa principal queda así:

```
frase = input().lower() #ingresar la frase 
nueva_frase = []
for palabra in frase.split():
  if len(palabra)>=6:
      nueva_frase.append(quitar_vocales(palabra))
  else:
      nueva_frase.append(palabra)
print(" ".join(nueva_frase))
```

Como ves se crea una lista auxiliar en la que meter la palabra procesada, o la palabra original, según su longitud. Finalmente se usa `" ".join()` para volver a juntar la lista auxiliar en una cadena, concatenando todos sus elementos usando el espacio como separador.

### Posible mejoras

Se puede reescribir la función que quita las vocales para que:

- No las quite si la palabra tiene menos de 6 letras
- Use otro mecanismo para quitarlas: iterar por las letras de la palabra y dejar pasar sólo las que no sean vocales (no estén en "aeiou"). Se puede usar además `.lower()` para que aunque la palabra contenga vocales mayúsculas, las quite también.
- Usar una expresión generadora para iterar por las letras.

```
def quitar_vocales_o_no(palabra):
  if len(palabra)<6:
      return palabra
  vocales = "aeiou"
  return "".join(letra for letra in palabra if letra.lower() not in vocales)
```

Ya que ahora es la función la que verifica la longitud, eso simplifica el bucle del programa principal, que puede reescribirse como una expresión generadora

```
frase = input()
print(" ".join(quitar_vocales_o_no(palabra) for palabra in frase.split()))
```

Ejemplo de ejecución:

```
Espero las VACACIONES con ansias
spr las VCCNS con nss
```